# Unable to perform SQL search on logstash index in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack, xpack, elasticsearch-sql

I have below indexes in the kibana when searched with below query.

```
GET /_xpack/sql?format=txt
{
    "query": "SHOW tables"
}
```

Output:

```
              name               |     type      
---------------------------------+---------------
.kibana                          |ALIAS          
.kibana_1                        |BASE TABLE     
.monitoring-es-6-2019.03.17      |BASE TABLE     
.monitoring-kibana-6-2019.03.17  |BASE TABLE     
.monitoring-logstash-6-2019.03.17|BASE TABLE     
bank                             |BASE TABLE     
logstash-2015.05.18              |BASE TABLE     
logstash-2015.05.19              |BASE TABLE     
logstash-2015.05.20              |BASE TABLE
```

When trying to search logstash table getting error as below.

```
GET _xpack/sql?format=txt
{
  "query": "select * from logstash-2015.05.18"
}
```

Error Output

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "line 1:23: mismatched input '-' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'ANALYZE', 'ANALYZED', 'AS', 'CATALOGS', 'COLUMNS', 'CURRENT', 'DAY', 'DEBUG', 'EXECUTABLE', 'EXPLAIN', 'FIRST', 'FORMAT', 'FULL', 'FUNCTIONS', 'GRAPHVIZ', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'HOUR', 'INNER', 'INTERVAL', 'JOIN', 'LAST', 'LEFT', 'LIMIT', 'MAPPED', 'MINUTE', 'MONTH', 'NATURAL', 'OPTIMIZED', 'ORDER', 'PARSED', 'PHYSICAL', 'PLAN', 'RIGHT', 'RLIKE', 'QUERY', 'SCHEMAS', 'SECOND', 'SHOW', 'SYS', 'TABLES', 'TEXT', 'TYPE', 'TYPES', 'VERIFY', 'WHERE', 'YEAR', '{LIMIT', IDENTIFIER, DIGIT_IDENTIFIER, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}"
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "line 1:23: mismatched input '-' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'ANALYZE', 'ANALYZED', 'AS', 'CATALOGS', 'COLUMNS', 'CURRENT', 'DAY', 'DEBUG', 'EXECUTABLE', 'EXPLAIN', 'FIRST', 'FORMAT', 'FULL', 'FUNCTIONS', 'GRAPHVIZ', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'HOUR', 'INNER', 'INTERVAL', 'JOIN', 'LAST', 'LEFT', 'LIMIT', 'MAPPED', 'MINUTE', 'MONTH', 'NATURAL', 'OPTIMIZED', 'ORDER', 'PARSED', 'PHYSICAL', 'PLAN', 'RIGHT', 'RLIKE', 'QUERY', 'SCHEMAS', 'SECOND', 'SHOW', 'SYS', 'TABLES', 'TEXT', 'TYPE', 'TYPES', 'VERIFY', 'WHERE', 'YEAR', '{LIMIT', IDENTIFIER, DIGIT_IDENTIFIER, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "input_mismatch_exception",
      "reason": null
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Can you please advice how we can do select query in this kind of senario.

Regards,
Hemanth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of double quotes to escape. Below query should resolve the issue.

```
POST _xpack/sql?format=txt
{
    "query": "select * from \"logstash-2015.05.18\""
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: tried above query still getting error.

{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "sql_illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Arrays (returned by [@tags]) are not supported"
      }
    ],
    "type": "sql_illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Arrays (returned by [@tags]) are not supported"
  },
  "status": 500
}

Comment: Make sure that you used this `"query": "select * from \"logstash-2015.05.18\""` and not this `"query": "select * from "logstash-2015.05.18""` Also let me know which version of _xpack are you using. One more note, xpack SQL feature doesn't support if your index has `nested` or `array` datatypes. Can you update and share me your mapping info for that index?

Comment: I could see Xpack version is 6.0.0.
```
GET /_xpack/sql?format=txt
{
    "query": "DESCRIBE \"logstash-2015.05.18\""
}
```
Above query is working fine and getting below output.

Output Link: 
https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/-1n5a31eNAD2hPsOQb7Aiw

can you please advice how to check index type is nested or array.

Thanks,
Hemanth.

Comment: @BitraHemanth Looks like there are certain fields which could be nested or array. At the moment I don't think elasticsearch-sql supports querying features for indexes having these datatypes. You can check the mapping details using `GET logstash-2015.05.18/_mapping`. If you can, could you execute that and post it in your question section.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.
I could query another index of similar kind of index, but not able to perform select on the logstash.

GET _xpack/sql?format=txt
{
  "query": "select * from \".monitoring-logstash-6-2019.03.17\""
}

Comment: @BitraHemanth Could you post the mapping details of any of these indexes. They both must have the same issue. I can look further into them.

Comment: Please find the mapping details for below indexes.

GET logstash-2015.05.18/_mapping

Output:

https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/-1n5a31eNAD2hPsOQb7Aiw


GET .monitoring-logstash-6-2019.03.17/_mapping

Output:

https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/X9WW6~0sbZDkdJATeL7hGQ

Comment: @BitraHemanth Yup. The indexes have arrays. I'm afraid ES SQL doesn't support them at the moment. :(